# Passing a List<object> to ASP NET Core MVC Action through jQuery Ajax returns zero count

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

**EDIT**

*I managed to pass the list to a HttpPost version of the Index method but now i need the data in my HttpGet Index as well. RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), filtered) doesnt seem to do the trick as the list in GET come with Cout = 0 again.*

I'm trying to make an ajax request to my Home/Index method that accepts a List of ProductListingViewModel. The action is hit but the List's count is always zero. The ajax data I send is JSON.stringified and it looks like this

```
[{"id":2,"name":"Anchovy In Oil","thumbnailSource":"http://dummyimage.com/64x126.png/dddddd/000000","price":1,"categories":["Fish","Food"]},
{"id":20,"name":"Cheese - Blue","thumbnailSource":"http://dummyimage.com/141x149.png/cc0000/ffffff","price":82,"categories":["Food"]},
{"id":17,"name":"Loafers","thumbnailSource":"http://dummyimage.com/80x101.png/5fa2dd/ffffff","price":60,"categories":["Shoes"]}
]
```

> And here is the **ViewModel**

```
public class ProductListingViewModel : IMapFrom<Product>, IHaveCustomMapping
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ThumbnailSource { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

> and the **AJAX**:

```
 var dataToSend = JSON.stringify(filtered);

        console.log("sending data to index:");
        console.dir(dataToSend);

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            traditional: true,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "products",
            data: dataToSend
        });
```

> Lastly the **HomeController's Index** method that gets hit
>   successfully but its first parameter's count is always ***zero*** even
>   though the data has been sent correctly

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(List<ProductListingViewModel> filtered, int? page,
        int pageSize = 20)
    {
        //some logic

        return View(PaginatedList<ProductListingViewModel>.Create(filtered, page ?? 1, pageSize));
    }
```

Anyone please give me a hand :)

Comment: Use 'post' request instead of get

Comment: Yes, i figured that out soon after i had posted my question. But still, since it is my Index method I need the HttpGet version of it too so i write a HttpGet overload of the method. Is there a way i can send the filtered list from my HttpPost Index method to my HttpGet index method. Returning RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), filtered) doesnt seem to do the trick, hits the Get Index successfully but filtered comes with Count 0 again.

Comment: A GET does not have a body so `contentType: 'application/json',` is pointless, and you sending a `string`, not a collection of objects. You bind in a GET method you would need to send a query string with `filtered[0].id=2&filtered[0].name=Anchovy&....` etc, which apart from the ugly query string would probably exceed the query string limit and throw an exception.

Comment: Its not clear why you think you should be sending a collection of complex objects to a GET, but it suggests a problem with the design of your app.

Comment: @StephenMuecke noted. Thank you. I'll rethink my code